# embed tag causing error in console

Tags: html, embed, typeerror, embed-tag

I have an embed tag displaying a SVG:

`<embed src="/img/mysvg.svg" style="max-width: 100%">`

It's causing an error in the console:
[image: Console Error]

When I comment out the embed tag the error goes away. Any ideas why this is happening?

I don't think it should be a factor but it's also inside a blade in a Laravel project

I get the same error in Safari except it's in kwift.SAFARI.min.js:1

Comment: What does the Javascript look like?

Comment: I don't have any JS linked to this page yet, that's why it's strange that it's causing a JS error

Answer (score 0):

why you use embed tag , Chrome Dev tool thinks is wrong , actuality it is not wrong in HTML , but better use img tag

```
<img src="/img/mysvg.svg" style="max-width: 100%"/>
```

Comment: I originally had it as a void element and only put the closing tag to see if it would remove the error but the error is still there

Comment: why you are using embed tag for svg file ??

Comment: by default svg is not supported in embed tag , HTML will show the file but
Chrome dev tool will not recognize it , and says TypeError , so better use <object> tag

Comment: or you can simple use <img> tag

Comment: I tried an img tag and the image wouldn't display. I also tried `<object data="/img/mysvg.svg" type="image/svg+xml"></object>` and am still getting the same error